# Display Mermaid diagram from C# variable in Polyglot notebook

Tags: mermaid, polyglot, dotnet-interactive

I know that Polyglot notebooks support Mermaid diagrams. But it doesn't support veriable sharing. Suppose I have diagram code in C# string variable. Are there any possibility to display that string as diagram?

Example:

```cs
// below diagram code was generated via some method
var mermaidCode = """
flowchart TD
    A --> B
""";

// here I would like to display mermaidCode as diagram
mermaidCode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way that generates a *Mermaid* output cell by means of a `MermaidMarkdown` display object:

```cs
#r "Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Mermaid.dll"
using Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Mermaid;

var mermaidCode = """
flowchart TD
    A --> B
""";

new MermaidMarkdown(mermaidCode)
```

[image: polyglot notebook screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Its litle late, but you can do this.

1 - generate a "mermaid" cell with

```
using Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive; 
using Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Commands;
    
await Kernel.Root.SendAsync(new SendEditableCode("mermaid", <yourMarkdown>));
```

2 - run the new generated cell

Comment: If you use ``Kernel.Root.SendAsync(new SubmitCode("mermaid", "<your-markdown>"))`` instead, it will run the mermaid output instead of generating a new cell each time.

Answer (score 0):

actually the SubmitCode does not work that way.
It has different arguments order.

```
await Kernel.Root.SendAsync(new SubmitCode("<your-markdown>", "mermaid", SubmissionType.Run));
```